# How to add box collision to subcomponent?

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

everyone. I am using ue4 blueprint to construct a pipe(Underground pipes), and I hope I can click the pipe then show the pipe's information. However I found that onclicked event works only when I clicked on the `Box collision` like this

[image]

My blueprint use the `Spline Component`, but when I adjust pipe in level, the collision box won't change ,please look my blueprint
[image]
[image]

then how can I set all the pipe's every sub `spline mesh component`'s `collision box` via construction script? Thanks very much!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, please click here (add spline mesh component function in blueprint)

then you will find the details on the right side, get the collision correct. I never know that this blueprint function has details too!